# How to package menu links as configuration?

Tags: 8

As a site builder I am looking for a module to package some menu links as configuration. I have looked at [Config Menu Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_config), but it does not seem very active and appears to have some critical bugs. Can anyone suggest an alternative please?

Note: the menu links would mainly be for admin purposes and have known paths. The intention is to simplify updates and add new features to multiple sites sharing the same configuration.

Comment: That's difficult. As far as I understand, menu links are entities. With entity IDs. Unique to each environment. These items then again link to other entities (nodes) with their own entity IDs. Same problem again. Same why taxonomy terms, nodes and users can't be exported. By the way, it seems you are asking for a module recommendation. Which is off-topic.

Comment: Thank you @leymannx. I should say that the menu links would mainly be for admin purposes and have known paths. The intention is to simplify updates and add new features to multiple sites sharing the same configuration.

Comment: Sounds you are better off providing them programmatically from your own custom module. You can put them in the toolbar, or provide your own route under /admin/config, or merge them in an existing menu.

Comment: Create [my_module.menu.links.yml](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-menu-links) files

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I'll give this a go